# How to completely sign out a user using Oauth Prompt?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I have been following the Oauth prompt sample [Oauth Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication). Its working great when I login properly and get a token. However I am working on the use case when a user logs in using the wrong credentials. I am using `await botAdapter.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context, ConnectionName, null, cancellationToken);` to sign the user out and it works since Oauth gets prompted again. However when the user clicks on sign in button again, it takes the wrong credentials again ( i.e same logged in credentials because of browser cache  ) and doesn't allow the user to use a different account. I am looking to gracefully sign the user out so that he can choose another account to login. I understand if I add this to the right tenant (add my bot to right AD identity) it wont allow the wrong email/credentials to even get through but its something I have to work through for now. I don't know if this is intended but the sign out only destroys the token doesn't log you out of Microsoft online.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `SignOutUserAsync` method only signs a user out of the token server, my guess is you will need to implement a custom method to handle a full sign out. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request) discusses sending a sign-out request and should serve as guidance on how to setup. If this isn't a perfect match, other options are listed in the menu tree.

Instead of relying on the `SignOutUserAsync` method, you would implement this feature in its place.

Comment: Yeah i figured that it wouldnt allow you to sign out of Microsoft identity platform. Just the bot so if you logged in again it would just get you straight to the bot. I just created an extra event when the signout button was clicked which would be captured on the directline incoming activities and trigger https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri using the IDP logout documentation after I wasn't getting anything directly from the bot. Thanks for your help.